# How to convert dynamic column into rows in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

**INPUT**

| product | country | brand | 01-01-2022 | 02-01-2022 | 03-01-2022 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| dairy milk | India | Cadbury | 10 | 20 | 30 |

**OUTPUT**

| product | country | brand | DATE | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| dairy milk | India | Cadbury | 01-01-2022 | 10 |
| dairy milk | India | Cadbury | 02-01-2022 | 20 |
| dairy milk | India | Cadbury | 03-01-2022 | 30 |

**INPUT**

| product | country | brand | 01-01-2022 | 02-01-2022 | 03-01-2022 | 04-01-2022 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| dairy milk | India | Cadbury | 10 | 20 | 30 | 40 |

**OUTPUT**

| product | country | brand | DATE | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| dairy milk | India | Cadbury | 01-01-2022 | 10 |
| dairy milk | India | Cadbury | 02-01-2022 | 20 |
| dairy milk | India | Cadbury | 03-01-2022 | 30 |
| dairy milk | India | Cadbury | 04-01-2022 | 40 |

Comment: Try using UNPIVOT: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/unpivot.html

Comment: ya i have tried it, but how can i take 01-01-2022,02-01-2022 into dynamic

Comment: @NickW could you plz help me with the command

Comment: @PonmathiRadhakrishnan so those dates could have different values such as 01-02-2022, 01-02-2022 etc? How about the number of columns? Does it also change?

Comment: i have tried with static its working ------------select * from Pivot_Unpivot
    unpivot(value for date in ("01/01/2022", "02/01/2022", "03/01/2022"))

Comment: @GokhanAtil yes

Comment: @GokhanAtil i have added the example above , kindly check

Comment: Please include code to reproduce your input date in your questions in future.  It took me as long to recreate your test data, as it did to write the solution.*

Answer (score 2):

Here's a dynamic solution using `object_construct` and `lateral flatten` .

First create some test data.

```
create or replace view data as 
SELECT
   *
FROM
   (VALUES (
            'dairy milk',
            'India',    
            'Cadbury',
            10, 
            20, 
            30))
 as v (PRODUCT,
       COUNTRY,
       BRAND,
       "01-01-2022",
       "02-01-2022",
       "03-01-2022")
;
```

I assume your date columns are quoted, although not shown as such in your question, as otherwise they are invalid column names.

```
with 
-- First create an object containing the contents of each row
ro as (select 
    PRODUCT, COUNTRY, BRAND,
    object_construct(*) row_obj
from data)
-- Lateral flatten the object, and filter out the columns that you don't want to pivot.
Select
    PRODUCT, COUNTRY, BRAND,  
    to_date( -- Note: Removing the " from quoted column names
            replace(key,'"')  
            ,'DD-MM-YYYY') as "DATE", value
from ro, lateral flatten (input => row_obj)
where key not in ('PRODUCT','COUNTRY','BRAND');
```

I've assumed that you want the DATE column in the result to be returned as a date type, hence the need for replace and cast to convert the column names you are un-pivoting.  If you are fine with the DATE column as varchar type, you can replace

```
to_date(
            replace(key,'"')  
            ,'DD-MM-YYYY') as "DATE"
```

with

```
key as "DATE"
```

Note: your columname DATE is a keyword and therefore needs to be quoted. I think its good practice to avoid using SQL keywords as object-names.

Answer (score 0):

One approach uses a `UNION ALL`:

```sql
SELECT product, country, brand, '2022-01-01' AS DATE, "01-01-2022" AS VALUE FROM yourTable
UNION ALL
SELECT product, country, brand, '2022-01-02', "02-01-2022" FROM yourTable
UNION ALL
SELECT product, country, brand, '2022-01-03', "03-01-2022" FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: Thanks,but this should be dynamic

Comment: ...then you need dynamic SQL